# Android - How can I replace the number in this type of string?

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, str-replace

does anyone know how can I replace the number in this type of string and delete the second part (if exists)?

I know this sound weird, let me explain.

The string to deal with is different each time:

The number (what I need to replace) can be from `1` digit up to `10` digits, from: `0` up to: `9999999999` (also could be zeros `0000000000`).

Always has a character before the number (could be any character, any case), like: `X0000`, `a00`, `h000000`, `G000`.

Sometimes might have another part following it (starts with a hyphen, I need to remove this part if exists), like: `X000-X00000`, `X0000-X00`, `X00-X0`.

Sometimes might have another extra character following it (could be any character, any case, starts with a hyphen, I need to keep this part if exists), like: `X00000-X`, `X0000-X000-X`, `a000-h`, `g00000-j00-Y`.

I don't know how to replace the first part (if exists), delete the second part (if exists) and keep the last part (if exists), this is an example of what I need:

```
X0000 > X1234
a00 > a12
h000000 > h123456
G000 > G123

X000-X000000 > X123  -  replace the first and delete the last
X0000-X000 > X1234 -  replace the first and delete the last
X00-X00 > X12 -  replace the first and delete the last

X00000-X > X12345-X -  replace only the first and keep the last
a000-h > a123-h -  replace it and keep the last

X0000-X000-X > X1234-X -  replace the first, delete the second and keep the last
g00000-j00-Y > g12345-Y -  replace the first, delete the second and keep the last
```

In this examples I used 0 and X mostly, but like explained, could be 0 or any number and could be X or any character (capital or lowercase).

EDIT: forgot to mention, I need to get that number, do a math with it and then replace it, is not just replacing.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you need to start using regular expressions

Comment: I edited my question, I forgot to mention the last part, any ideas on how to do it using regular expressions? Thanks.

Comment: check these tutorials: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to do it by using `replace()` and `substring()` is as follows:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "X000-X";
    String replacement = "123";
    int ls = input.lastIndexOf("-");
    int fs = input.indexOf("-");
    System.out.println("Extracted Number: " + (fs < 1 ? input.substring(1) : 
                                                        input.substring(1,fs)));
    System.out.println("Final Output: " + input.substring(0,1) + replacement + 
                       (ls != fs || fs == input.length() - 2 ? input.substring(ls) : ""));
}
```

Output:

```
Extracted Number: 000
Final Output: X123-X
```

Comment: Will it work with a string like X000-X and like X000 too?

Comment: @Minion Yes, it will work with all the cases you have given above.

Comment: @Pooya Updated the solution. It extracts and print the number now.

Comment: @user2004685 the OP mentioned "I need to get that number, do a math with it and then replace it" so I think the extracted number should be stored in an integer

Comment: @Pooya This is just a sample code snippet which tells you how to approach the problem. One can easily parse the string into an integer and do whatever calculations necessary and use that instead of the `replacement` string.

Comment: @Minion Your Welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll only give you example of one, And you can follow the same as per the requirements, OR you can separate some lines into separate methods as well as per your requirements,

```
   String value = "X000-X000000";
    if(value.contains("-")){
        String match="";
        String[] elements = value.split("-");

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(elements[0]); //For the first element that is X000

        while (matcher.find()) {
            match = matcher.group(); //Numeric is match that is 000
        }

    //Do whatever you want to do with 000 here like I replaced 123 here

     elements[0] = elements[0].replace(match, String.valueOf(123));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(String s : elements) {
            builder.append(s + "-");
        }
        value = builder.toString().substring(0,builder.length()-1); //Your final value that can be returned as well


    }
```

Comment: It does not delete the second part. For Example, `X000-X000000` gives something like `X123-X000000` and not just `X123` as expected. Maybe you can fix the solution.

Comment: @user2004685 yah. His requirements is too large and sometime he wants to delete, Sometime he doesn't. But he can easily delete specific elements by replacing it to ""(empty) in the elements array which was separated. Or if he wants only first part using only `elements[0]` also fulfill the requirements. It's all based on requirements. And thank you very much for suggesting, I appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks and you were too.